# Reading from a configuratioin file

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, bufferedreader, filereader

I am very new to java and I have been looking at tutorials but I am struggling to figure out how to read intial configuration data for my program from a text file. The input data is in the form:

```
Class A: paramater 1, paramater 2, paramater 3
Class B: paramater 4, paramater 5
Class C: paramater 4, paramater 5
Class D: paramater 6
Class E: paramater 6
Class F: paramater 6
```

Where the objects from classes B and C goes into an arraylist in class A and classes D, E and F go into an arraylist in the class which is reading the file. All class names are Strings and all of the paramaters are ints.

I get that I need to import the bufferedReader and fileReader but I can't figure out how to use them.

The unfortunately little code wihch I have related to this:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Garden {

    ArrayList<Flower> flowerbed = new ArrayList<Flower>();
    Hive hive = null;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader("myGarden.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(filereader);


        }catch(FileNotFoundException filenotfoundexception){
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }catch(IOException ioexception){
            System.out.println("File input error occured!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to use a properties file to load, get and store values with keys, It is very easy and useful.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html